# How to terminate adb logcat in java application

Tags: java, process, logcat, terminate, ctrl

Hello I have to develop adb logs capture tool, I have tried with below code

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb logcat -c");
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb logcat");
```

So I will start logger using **START** button so logs are getting started
but I am not able to stop logging as **START** button is always disabled after starting log and not able to select **STOP** button.

Normally in command line we can terminate **logcat** using **ctrl + c**

So how I can terminate logcat in this scenario I tried `process.destory()`.

[image]

I tried using process.destroy() but on start and stop text file is getting created to collect logs but logs will continue to print in console in eclipse so process is not destroyed, and until and unless I close application text files size is not updated.

After several Start and Stop
[image]

Still logs will be coming in eclipse console,
[image]

Comment: why process.destory() not work? process.destory() will close this process

Comment: Yes it work if I write it in on START button action but actually I need to terminate logcat when user click STOP button, so in START I am starting logcat and same time start button is getting disabled and as process is continued to capture logs not able to click STOP button

Comment: Do you mean you have two button "START", "STOP", once "START" clicked, start the adb, then "STOP" clicked stop the adb?

Answer (score 0):

Thread needed in your case.

```
final Process exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("E:\\Android\\sdk\\platform-tools\\adb.exe logcat");

        //get the input stream
        InputStream inputStream = exec.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader buInputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        final BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(buInputStreamReader);
        final StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

        new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    String str = null;
                    while ((str = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        buf.append(str);
                        buf.append("\n");
                        System.out.println(str);
                    }
                }catch (Exception ignore){}
            }
        }.start();

        JButton btnStop=new JButton("Stop");
        btnStop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                exec.destroy();        
            }
        });
```

Comment: I tried the above solution but the number of times I start and stop every time text file is getting created I have added that part but exec.destory() not destroying parent process it only destroys sub process and when I will stop/kill application completely then only data in files is updating.

Comment: what do you mean the parent process? the adb.exe should be closed once exec.destory() is called

Comment: Yes on Stop it should stop logging completely

Comment: Either adb.exe should close/stop or it should release text file on stop button

Answer (score 0):

```
String command = "ADB_PATH"+-s {deviceID} shell logcat -b crash;

      public LinkedHashSet<String> getAllDataFromCommand_v1(String command) {
                LinkedHashSet<String> resultSet = new LinkedHashSet<>();
                String s = null;
                try {
                    Process p =     Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
                    InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream());
                    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(in);
                    BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
                    // read the output from the command
                    System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n"+command+"\n");
                    while (stdInput.ready()) {
                        s = stdInput.readLine();
                        resultSet.add(s);
                        System.out.println(s);
                    }
                    while (stdError.ready()) {
                        s = stdError.readLine();
                        System.out.println(s);
                        if(s.contains("not found")) {
                            System.out.println("Closing command");
                        }
                    }   
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return resultSet;
            }
```

Same code can be use to get all the logs. It will capture all the logs till input is available.